# Derivation of $1 = x^2+y^2$ with respect to time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am studying differential algebraic equations. Given the following equation:

$1 = x^2+y^2$

Differentiate this equation with respect to time.
The correct solution is:

$0=2x \dot x + 2y \dot y $

But why? 
My wrong idea was:

$0=2x+2y$

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

If $x=x(t)$ then
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left[x^2\right] = 2x \frac{dx}{dt}
$$
and same for $y$ by the Chain Rule.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

it is supposed that $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$ are functions of time, so you have to use the chain rule.

E.g., deriving $x^2$:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} [x(t)]^2= 2x\frac{dx}{dt}=2x \dot x 
$$

Comment: I got my wires crossed :) - in normal "school-math", the derviation of $x^2$ is $2x$ right? Not $2x \dot x$?

Comment: In  normal "school-math" what is the derivative of $f^2(x)$ with respect to $x$?  Here you have an $x^2(t)$.....

Comment: Does that mean: In normal "school math"$: \frac{d}{dx}[x(?)]^2$ by chain rule $2x*\frac{dx}{dx}$ where the fractino cancels?

Answer (score 1):

Here $x,y$ are functions of $t$, so what you really have is 
$$1\equiv x^2(t)+y^2(t).$$
Now, treat LHS as a constant function $f(t)$, then differentiate LHS and RHS simultaneously.